# How can you use Firebase tools with a work mail that is not from Google Workspace

Tags: firebase, microsoft365

I'll put this in points to be clear:

1. My company work mail (xyz@mycompany.com) is hosted with Microsoft 365
2. I want to use Firebase tools like Firestore, Functions, Hosting, etc
3. Obviously I don't have a Google account and I want to use this work email id to access firebase console.

How or Can we use Firebase without having a Google account?

Comment: Actually Firebase runs on top of Google Cloud. So definitely you need a Google Account!

Comment: Yeah! But there should be a way to use this mail id to access firebase console right? Because all my tools will be managed by admin@xyz.com and I would not like just this to be some other gmail.com.

Comment: If `admin@xyz.com` is a Google Business Email, then it would be possible I think.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, there is a way. I've contacted the support team and I got this.

> To give you an insight, Google login is required to use Firebase. If you don’t want to use a Gmail Google login, and have an alternate email address, you may sign up using this [link](https://accounts.google.com/SignUpWithoutGmail?hl=en). This Google account will only be used for identification and login, and won't be tied to any Gmail, Google+, or other Google products.

So, there is a way. And yes, it is working. Successfully using admin@xyz.com (Work mail by Microsoft 365) and a different password though to use firebase.

Comment: Is this non-straight way still exists or you can now sign in directly with the custom Microsoft email ?

Comment: @sheko The MS account 'admin@xyz.com' doesn't know anything about the 'admin@xyz.com' in Firebase ( .. _and a different password though to use firebase_). It's just a firebase account using the same email address, that's all.

Comment: @kingpong after i create that 'admin@xyz.com'  from google with a new password  will it be able to access all google services like any other gmail or email created from google workspace ?

Comment: @sheko Depends what you mean by "_after i create that 'admin@xyz.com' from google_'". If you create it using your Firebase project credentials, then it's not tied to anything else. You can create such an account with login/email 'admin@xyz.com' in your Firebase project ShekoProject1 and I can use the same login/email in my KingPongProject1. Otherwise Firebase emails in all Firebase projects would require uniqueness, which would often fire alerts like 'Error, user test@email.xxx already exists in another project' ..

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to access GCP without a Google account and a Google Billing account. You could look into an organization account but this still requires a master Google account to set up additional users through the Google Identity Platform.

This also supports creating a Google Cloud Platform Organization, but would most likely be outside of your original interest.

https://developers.google.com/identity/